# Why does a symbol from SF Symbols in Xcode stays black in renderingMode (.original)

Tags: swift, xcode, sf-symbols

[Пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV4W3.png)

SF Symbols Pro: 16.0d18e1
Xcode: 11.6(11E708)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I make the symbol have a color appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Although your version of the font is new enough to support the multicolored SF Symbols, your version of Xcode is not. This will require version 12+ of Xcode with an iOS 14 simulator.

Same code (with sizing and background to make it more legible) running on Xcode 12.4/iOS 14.4:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: THX so much, im rookie

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark